# Specific multiplatform application. Can it be done good?

Tags: android, linux, windows, user-interface

I'm looking for technology to develop **one** application for Windows, Linux and Android.
Is there a technology to do this task not writing more than one application and fulfilling constraints written below?

Application, that:

- works offline
- is capable of being a widget in java (swing) application
- has closed source code (opposed to html5)
- uses socket-like tcp communication (in LAN etc.)
- is mainly GUI

Technology has to be available for **free for commercial** use.

As i found, **not sufficient** ones:

- PhoneGap is only for mobile
- HTML/JavaScript gives open-source code
- There can't be any serverside work (like ASP.NET/PHP etc) because it has to work offline
- When writing two Java applications there is nothing to share between Android and Windows/Linux application, because it's GUI mainly, ActionListeners etc are platform dependant.
- Xamarin is not free

I've read today all similar questions to this one here, but none of them gives enough information. I've been searching on the internet for 3 days.

I would like application to be written in java or html/css/JavaScript, but
if there are possibilities in other language I would like to hear about them too.

There is **no need** for application to look native or to be super efficient.

Comment: If something with question is wrong, leave me a comment so i'll fix it! :)

Comment: I think it's not possible to build a good application that runs on the 3 systems you have specified, mainly because Android is a touch-based OS while Windows and Linux are mainly not. For the application to be successful you need to consider a different GUI for Android vs Windows/Linux.

Comment: It will be closed for the same reason the last one was.  And doubtless, some will downvote since it is neither constructive nor does it meet the definition of questions in the FAQ. In addition, deleting a question then repeating it is not good behaviour on a voluntary, community curated forum.

Comment: You will notice an "edit" link beneath the tags on the question. If you wish to change a question (e.g., add the bulleted list of technologies you don't like), edit the existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Qt might satisfy all those requirements. http://qt-project.org/

Things that don't quite line up: it's not 100% zero-cost and it's C++, not Java.

Comment: "I think Qt might satisfy all those requirements." I will know after some 13h, thx!

  "[...] not Java." there is [QTJambi](http://qt-jambi.org/), but it seems to be not developed since 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement for your application to be a Swing widget means that it will not run on Android, as Android does not support Swing.

So, as far as I know, no, there is not one technology that will fulfill all of your requirements.

Comment: "Your requirement for your application to be a Swing widget means that it will not run on Android, as Android does not support Swing." 
This can be done using html/JavaScript + WebView functionality on Android and the same on PC(JRE), but html is open-source.

Comment: It can be done on both, but not with exactly the same codebase, which is, i believe, what the OP was asking.